# Google Analytics: Why does my data in GA say that users have landed on the checkout page when I know this is impossible?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

This questions is in reference to a client I am currently working with, unfortunately I cannot disclose who the client is. They have an e-commerce website and have very high volumes of traffic, around 6 - 9 thousand sessions per day, and around 5 - 8 users per day. From this they have about a 5% conversion rate.

I am spending a lot of time at the moment looking at the conversion funnel, how they choose products, go to the basket, checkout and then view the confirmation page. It is impossible for users to 'land' on the checkout page as products only stay in the basket for 20 minutes and the only link to the checkout page is from the basket.

However, we are seeing about 1% of traffic that views the checkout page apparently landed on it, resulting in around 30-40% bounce rate. I know it does not seem like a lot of users, but in a month it works out at a couple of hundred people each month apparently landing straight on the checkout page. I created a segment to drill down into this traffic and saw that the source was a variety of referral, organic, direct, and even from social and email campaigns. There is no consistency.

I would just like to know if anyone has experienced anything similar with pages apparently having entrances when it cannot be so and what, if anything, I can do to fix it.

Thank you!

Elexa

Comment: I assume your have added your own domain added to the referral exclusion list, so they will keep the original traffic source even if their session is interrupted somehow. Check page depth (might be 1 or at least very low) and avg. session duration to see if this is what happens.

Comment: At midnight, sessions will split into new sessions.  Also, GA uses last non-direct attribution, so when they go direct to the checkout page, it gets attributed to the previous source/medium.   Might explain some of what you are seeing.